# angular httpclient return an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
private getScmServiceMeta(serviceId: string): Observable<any> {
    let service = this.getServiceItem(serviceId);

    if (service) {
        return this.httpClient.get(serviceUri).map((res: Response) => {
                return _.get(res, 'data.serviceinfo');
            })
    } else {
        return Observable.throw('backend server error');
    }
}

public inquireScmData(serviceId: string, params: object, templateId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getScmServiceMeta(serviceId).map((serviceInfo: any) => {

        let uri = serviceInfo.routeTemplate;

        // How to return the _.get(res, 'data') as an Observable ???
        return this.httpClient.get(uri).map((res: Response) => {
            if (_.startsWith(_.get(res, 'status.code'), '200')) {
                return _.get(res, 'data');
            } else {
                throw ('status code error');
            }
        })
    })
}
```

as the above code, I need to return an observable when call the function 'inquireScmData', but inside the function, it need to call another function 'getScmServiceMeta' which is also asynchronous and return also an Observable, so how to return the '_.get(res, 'data')'  as an Observable??? 
thanks

Comment: return Observable.of(_.get(res, 'data') )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rxjs` gives you a static method on Observable to do this.

```
Observable.of( _.get(res, 'data') );
```

Though, you'll then have an `Observable<Observable<Observable<any>>>`. Is that what you are intending, or do you just want to chain "async" operations. If so, you should maybe leave your code as is, and use `mergeMap`.

```
public inquireScmData(serviceId: string, params: object, templateId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.getScmServiceMeta(serviceId).mergMap((serviceInfo: any) => {

    let uri = serviceInfo.routeTemplate;

    return this.httpClient.get(uri).map((res: Response) => {
      if (_.startsWith(_.get(res, 'status.code'), '200')) {
        return _.get(res, 'data');
      } else {
        throw ('status code error');
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: shouldn't he use `switchMap` in this case?